# How to use three-wire Li-Po battery with built-in thermistor?

Tags: batteries, pcb

I am new to electronics and am trying to make something with a 3.7C 500mAh Li-Po battery. There is a temperature wire (white) and I was wondering if I could leave it unconnected?

Also how would a 3-wire battery (with temperature wire) compare to a 2-wire battery (no temperature wire) compare in terms of endurance?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that battery itself has a thermistor, [which is used to monitor temperature during charging and provide feedback for the charging device](https://www.ametherm.com/blog/thermistors/thermistors-ntc-thermistor-temperature-sensors-provide-li-ion-battery-safety/) for safety reasons.

Here is a schematic that might help explain what happens inside your battery pack ([PDF from Mouser, page 3](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/pov_protection_temperature_chip-ntc-thermistor_en.pdf)):

[image]

As you can see, you can operate the battery without connecting thermistor wire.